# Django Model Import Error: ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a new app "grn" in my django project and tried to import the models from another app named "packsapp" in the same project like this:

Models.py

```
from ..packsapp.models import *
```

But I got the following error:

> ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Here's the structure of the app:

```
yantra_packs

grn
--migrations
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
media
packsapp
--migrations
  templates
  templatetags
  views1
    __init__.py
    apps.py
    decorators.py
    forms.py
    models.py
    urls.py
    views.py
```

How can I import the models of the `packsapp` in the `grn` ??

Comment: you can import like: `from project_root.app_name.models import *`

Comment: @MehaParekh I tried this and got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yantra_packs.packsapp'`

Comment: did you add `packsapp` in installed_apps in settings.py file?

Comment: yes I have both of them in my Installed_apps

Comment: Did you import something from grn into packsapp?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The root directory of a Django project is not a Python package or module. So relative imports across Django apps will not work. Use an absolute import instead:

```
from packsapp.models import *
```